# How can i get values from one jsp page to another jsp without redirecting to another page?

Tags: jsp

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="page1">        
</body>
```

This is my `page1.jsp` page,when i click on this i need to get the value in `result.jsp` page *without changing the browser header*.

in my project i have 4 jsp pages named `page1.jsp`,`page2.jsp`,`page3.jsp` and `page4.jsp`

when i click on any page, result should come in `result.jsp`.

suppose if i clicked on `page2` result should come in `result.jsp` only,all pages have same input button value are page1,page2,page3 and page4

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/result.jsp
```

This is my browser header. thanks your help.

Comment: [read parameters passed by one jsp to another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20761294/1031945)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use data in one jsp page to another jsp page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941440/how-to-use-data-in-one-jsp-page-to-another-jsp-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), Its used to GET/POST data values to any page from Client to server. Without redirecting user to other page (changing URL in address-bar)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("button").click(function(){
                var value=$(this).val(); //it will get value of clicked button

                $("#result_div").load('result.jsp?param='+value); //it will make ajax call to result.jsp by GET method
            });
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="value1" />

        <div id="result_div">
            JSP Result will be loaded here.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, I've use GET method and passed parameter named `param` that you'l have to read in result.jsp. Whatever result is given by `result.jsp` It will be loaded in #result_div

Useful Links:

https://api.jquery.com/load/

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: could you explain the same logic using this jsp,please.

Comment: Actually JSP is not everything. After all what you need is facility from Client side. For that you'l need to write some code in client-side scripting.

jQuery is very easy, you can make async calls to server and get/post data. If you want sample code, I can help you with that.

Comment: Before I write, please clarify, What value you want to pass in your `result.jsp` page?
Is it value="page1" of button? And also clarify which method you are handling in your JSP? (GET or POST)

Comment: use any get/post,when i click on page1,value of page1 should display in result.jsp,and if i click on page2 ,value of page2 should display in reult.jsp,vice versa,

Comment: i dont want to use jquery/any other technique,i want to use only jsp,thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, Then its your choice. Sometimes we should understand client-side scripting and server side scripting. Anyways.. GOod luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
request.getParameter("<input_name_given_in_previous_page>");
```

and for sending parameters, use **form** tag in HTML.

example:

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="frmLogin" action="redirect.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="login_submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**redirect.jsp**

```
<%
    //it's demo only. 
    String u_n=request.getParameter("user_name");
    out.println("Hello "+u_n);
%>
```

Comment: Asker don't want user to redirect to another page, he said "Header should not change"  i.e. URL in address-bar.